# Is it still possible to do ContentOverride in Winforms ViewModels?

Tags: mdriven

Previously it was possible to use ContentOverride in Winforms ViewModels.

Is this still possible in MDriven 7.0.0.11262?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any changes so it should work as before. The ContentOverride signal the render-logic (Eco.ViewModel.WinForms.ViewModelUserControl) to call the OnColumnUIOverride event with the following argument:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Arguments for the OnColumnUIOverrideArgs event; fired to allow for override of column render.
  /// If you have other UI components that you want to use in ViewModel driven UI's this event provides
  /// a hook point to inject them.
  /// </summary>
  public class OnColumnUIOverrideArgs : EventArgs
  {
    public ViewModel ViewModel;
    /// <summary>
    /// The Column in question
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelColumn ViewModelColumn;
    /// <summary>
    /// What kind of UI we had in mind
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelUIComponentType ViewModelUIComponentType;
    /// <summary>
    /// Set this to false to stop us from calling default logic
    /// </summary>
    public bool ContinueWithDefault;
  }
```